# How to generate HTTP ca .cert?

Tags: security, certificate, https, openssl, tls

If I use to generate a certificate + private key pair, with the following command on Linux:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

This will generate two files (key.pem and cert.pem) and require myself to input a passphrase that encrypts/decrypts the private key; can someone give me a hint how to generate a ca .cert? Any beginner level explanation is welcome. I am trying to follow:

> messages should ideally be signed using an X509 certificate keypair.
> This allows both parties to verify that the message came from the
> correct party, and that it was not tampered with in transport. It does
> not provide message encryption; for that, a transport-level encryption
> (TLS) should be used.

***UPDATE***

To be more specific I am using [this](https://openleadr.org/docs/) Python framework (aiohttp apps) for client/server HTTP communication. [Here](https://github.com/OpenLEADR/openleadr-python/tree/main/certificates) in the git repo, they have a `generate_certs.sh` where if you run this in BASH it will generate all of these keys & crt files as shown in the screen shot below. CLIENT is VEN and SERVER is VTN:

[image]

I can make this framework communication work with HTTP but I am a bit confused on what all is need for TLS HTTPS where they [have some information on message signing](https://openleadr.org/docs/message_signing.html).

When I configure the aiohttp apps, what do I all need to include? The `generate_certs.sh` doesn't prompt for a passphrase.

For the [server](https://openleadr.org/docs/api/openleadr.html#module-openleadr.server) if I use this configuration below:

```py
# Create the server object
server = OpenADRServer(vtn_id='cloud_vtn_tls',
                       http_host='0.0.0.0',
                       cert='./certificates/dummy_vtn.pem',
                       key='./certificates/dummy_vtn.pem',
                       http_cert='./certificates/dummy_vtn.pem',
                       http_key='./certificates/dummy_vtn.pem',
                       ven_lookup=ven_lookup_function,
                       http_ca_file='./certificates/dummy_ca.crt',
                       )
```

And [client](https://openleadr.org/docs/api/openleadr.html#module-openleadr.client):

```py
# Create the client object
client = OpenADRClient(ven_name='dan_ven1',
                         vtn_url='https://11.12.13.14:8080/OpenADR2/Simple/2.0b',
                         cert='./certificates/dummy_ven.crt',
                         key='./certificates/dummy_ven.key',
                         ca_file='./certificates/dummy_ca.crt',
                         vtn_fingerprint='59:4D:D8:CD:35:8E:E7:F7:86:94')
```

The server script errors out like I am missing something when I start it.

```py
    (python_env) bbartling@localhost:/var/lib/openleadr-python$ python vtntestcerts.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/lib/openleadr-python/vtntestcerts.py", line 59, in <module>
        server = OpenADRServer(vtn_id='cloud_vtn_tls',
      File "/var/lib/openleadr-python/openleadr/server.py", line 109, in __init__
        self.ssl_context.load_cert_chain(http_cert, http_key, http_key_passphrase)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to accomplish. A self-signed certifiate (or any certificate, really) is valid on its own if you “manually” trust it. A certificate authority is only required if you want to establish a chain of trust. Do you know what you want? Or are you following some guide? In that case, please provide a link of possible.

Comment: I actually dont know what I need here. In the "EDIT" thats the best I have for any links

Comment: Well the edits are more like what you tried. That’s also good to know, but you quote some sort of instructions. What are they from?

Comment: The code is from the documentation on how to configure your Python aiohttp apps

Comment: That quote also from the documentation for message signing. https://openleadr.org/docs/message_signing.html

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (please edit your question so I can make it less partial):

The command line in your question generates a self-signed certificate plus the key to use it. That's normally all you have to do if you want a client or a server certificate.

"CA" means "certificate authority", and this is an extra "institution" for lack of a better word that then would sign your certificates. Unless you want lots of certificates all signed by the same certificate authority, because you only want to give the other parties the single "signing" certificate to trust, this is **not** what you need. (But you didn't explain your use case, that is, **why** you need a certificate).

If what you want is a single file instead of two files, there's a number of different file formats for that. One is called PKCS12, those typically have `.p12` or `.pfx` endings. You can use `openssl` to create those, if needed. But details depend on **which programs** you want to use your certificate with, please edit the question and add this information.

---

I am not familiar with OpenADR, but the script you linked generates a CA certificate and then **signs** both the server and the client cert with it. This means means when the server checks the client cert, or vica versa, the client checks the server cert, both need to trust the CA certificate.

So all the certificates should have been properly created for you by executing the shell script. If you didn't do this, you need to execute it - your single command line is not enough to generate all certificates.

As for the "file not found" message, either you have not run the shell script, or the relative paths do not work - try absolute paths instead.

Also, I am missing the `http_key_passphrase` parameter in the server (unless that is given somewhere else).

---

The script uses `genrsa` to generate the keys in an additional step. `man genrsa` tells you there's a `-passout` option, `man openssl` describes the format, so try adding `-passout 'pass:mypassphrase'` to all of the three keys which you think should have a passphrase. And if you don't want the passphrase in the script, use one of the other methods.

I do not know passphrases for which certs are supported by your framework, though, so first I'd try to get everything to work without passphrases ...

Comment: I added a ton more information under the EDIT. Any information or tips GREATLY appreciated....

Comment: Thanks for all of the info you have listed. When I run this in `bash generate_certs.sh` there is no prompt to generate a passphrase, but when I run `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365` this will prompt for a passphrase. So confusing : ( If I use this only, `bash generate_certs.sh` how do I get a passphrase from this process? Thank you for any response